# What happens to the photon if the frequency is lower than the threshold frequency?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

An electron is ejected only if the frequency of light is greater than the threshold frequency. What happens to the photon if the frequency is lower than the threshold frequency?

Comment: What do you mean "what happens" to it?

Comment: What change does it experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photon can be reemited with the same frequency if it collides with a strongly bound electron (Rutherford scattering) and can be reemited with different frequency of it collides with a weakly bound electron (Compton scattering).

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to the photon if the frequency is lower than the
>   threshold frequency?

The idea is that there is a certain threshold energy required to remove an electron from an atom to far away from the atom (the work function). The absorption of the photon supplies this energy. This is an electronic process that depends on the electromagnetic interaction between the electron and the material. It the photon has less energy then it may not get absorbed by an *electronic* process. However, in real life, it can still get absorbed by, e.g., processes involving phonons.

Comment: Is a lower frequency photon always absorbed or is there a possibility for it to do something else too?

Comment: There is a possibility that it is not absorbed. Even for photons with energy above the work function there is still a *possibility* that it is not absorbed. In general the absorption cross-section for a given photon energy has to be calculated based on the excitation spectrum of the material the photon is passing through